# How does arguments.callee actually work?

Tags: jquery

I have this code which works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#run").click(function() {
        $("div:animated").toggleClass("colored");
    });

    function animateIt() {
        $("#mover").slideToggle("slow", animateIt);
    }
    animateIt();
});
```

With `arguments.callee` we call a function itself so we do not need a name for a function. So this, should also work, but it doesn't. Can anyone tell me why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#run").click(function() {
        $("div:animated").toggleClass("colored");
    });

    function() {
        $("#mover").slideToggle("slow", arguments.callee);
    }
});
```

Comment: That is invalid javascript. You have to give a name to your function declaration.

Comment: @Esailija, citation needed. Looks to me like a [declaration of an anonymous function which is never used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11755677/7724).

Comment: Where is variable called "arguments" declared?

Comment: arguments.callee should be avoided. It is deprecated on ECMAscript 5

Comment: @AlexanderSitnikov , the `arguments` object is part of every function call. Check out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: @bzlm Here's the [Firebug](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/1451/firebugo.png) and [Chrome's dev tools](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/1376/chromedevtools.png) references.

Comment: @bzlm you cannot declare a function like this, it's a syntax error. Function declaration must have a name. IIFE is completely different and legit, but it was hard to see the intention here because he doesn't even attempt to call the function.

Comment: @Esailija, I see. Thanks. Didn't know there was a [hard difference between function expressions and function declarations](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original script, you declare the function `animateIt` and then you immediately call it, but in the modified script, you declare the closure without ever calling it.

You should try changing this:

```
function() {
  $("#mover").slideToggle("slow",arguments.callee);
}
```

with this:

```
(function() {
  $("#mover").slideToggle("slow",arguments.callee);
})();
```

that is, you both declare and call the closure on the same line.

Pleases remember that, as far as I know, the usage of `arguments.callee` and `arguments.caller` is quite discouraged and should be avoided.

Comment: You finished writing before I got to half of it, have a free [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAjhF/).